# VSCode "Remote - SSH" setting `DISPLAY` variable?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Anyone know why DISPLAY is getting set here in VSCode? I turned off auto-port forwarding in settings, but it still is set on opening a new integrated terminal. This actually interferes with running Cypress tests for a team I build for.

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

I believe this is part of the SSH plugin for remote connections, as a local integrated terminal is unset

```
[147dda3a79b0 ~]$ echo $DISPLAY

[147dda3a79b0 ~]$
```

This tends to mess up running Cypress web tests on my development desktop. Anyone know where this is set from? I suppose I could always add `unset DISPLAY` into `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: is there anything WSL-related in this setup? or Code OSS devcontainer-related?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to modify your shell profile file, there is an alternative approach you can try. You can override the DISPLAY environment variable directly in the VSCode integrated terminal settings.

Open the settings in VSCode by clicking on the gear icon in the lower left corner and selecting "Settings" from the menu. Alternatively, you can use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + , (comma) to open the settings.

In the search bar at the top of the settings, type "terminal.integrated.env.*" to filter the settings related to the integrated terminal environment variables.

Look for the setting called "Terminal > Integrated > Environment: Linux" and click on the "Edit in settings.json" link next to it. If the setting is not present, you can manually add it to the settings.json file.

In the settings.json file, add the following line:

"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
"DISPLAY": ""
}
Save the settings.json file

Empty string will override the value of DISPLAY that is automatically set, this will only affect the integrated terminal in VSCode not others.